Smallest singular value of matrix sinh
I'm looking for a strictly positive lower bound on the smallest singular value of $$\sinh(X) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{e^X - e^{-X}}{2}.$$ Unfortunately $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is not positive semidefinite, or even Hermitian, but all its eigenvalues do have positive real-part.
Any idea how to obtain a bound in terms of the eigenvalues or singular values of $X$?
What I really want, of course, is an upper bound on $\| \sinh(X)^{-1}\|$, so it is not enough for $\sinh(X)$ to just be invertible.

What do you mean by $\sinh(X)$? Are you independently applying a function to each entry of $X$, or are you computing the result of $\frac 1{1!}X^1 + \frac 1{3!}X^3 + \frac 1{5!}X^5 + \cdots$?

@BenGrossmann, I mean the limit of the infinite series.
